# How do I resize a DIV to full screen in a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function maximize(){
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    var height  = document.body.clientHeight;
    var body = document.body;
    var div = document.getElementById(main-window);

    <-- Need here some code for assignind div-s height to browser height
    make_draggable();
};
```

This is the code, I need to full screen the window to size of my window.

There is a problem, because my div is draggable, and resizable to and when I am writing code for full screen, drag and resize stop working.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What's the point of a fullscreen draggable div?

Comment: it's for chat, when it's not full screen, it's draggable
but i need to full screen chat window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery in your site, you could try this:

```
function maximize(){

    $('#main-window').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());

    make_draggable();
};
```

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwk5sxo9/)